# .addClass for multiple label elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply a class to the  and  below I am not sure of the syntax to do this.

`$(fieldInError).addClass('error')`   works perfectly just trying to figure out how to apply it to the labels.

```
<script language="javaScript">
    var fieldError = '#phone,#email';                                           
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(fieldInError).addClass('error');
    });
</script>

<label for="phone">Phone #:</label>
<input  type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
<br/><br/>

<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input  type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('label').addClass('error');
```

Just use the element selector

If you only want to add them to the labels associated with the fields then you can try this

```
var fieldInError = '#phone,#email';
$(fieldInError).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('error');
    $('label[for="' + $this.attr('name')  + '").addClass('error');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('label[for="phone"], label[for="email"]').addClass('error');
```